# laravel artisan command cron job is not working on ubuntu server

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, cron

I am new to Ubuntu server and i install cron job and then make new cron job and no idea why its not working. My application is in Laravel so i have to run artisan command through cron job! When i am in project through root cmd `artisan`-command run properly but in cron did not run it.

[here is my cron job listed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0tZS.png)

I check the if its running or not like this:

```
# sudo grep -i cron /var/log/syslog|tail -3
```

This is the output:

```
Jan 21 09:30:01 liedergut CRON[5222]:(root) CMD (/path/to/php/bin/php /var/www/html/artisan shows:fetchrss >> /dev/null 2>&1)

Jan 21 09:30:01 liedergut CRON[5223]: (root) CMD (php /var/www/html/artisan shows:fetchrss >> /dev/null 2>&1)
```

Comment: Your third cronjob (unfortunately I can't copy/paste it, because image) looks like it could run, I doubt your `php` executable is in `/var/www/html`. You can find out where it is using `whereis php`. Also there's a [Laravel documentation page](https://laravel.com/docs/master/scheduling) on how to set up cronjobs/schedules

Comment: @kerbholz it try every way to list job

`* * * * * /path/to/php/bin/php /var/www/html/artisan shows:fetchrss >> /dev/null 2>&1`
`* * * * * php /var/www/html/artisan shows:fetchrss >> /dev/null 2>&1`

`* * * * * /var/www/html/php artisan shows:fetchrss >> /dev/null 2>&1`


yes php is executable in **var/www/html **
if work there fine

Comment: I'm 99,7% sure `/var/www/html/php` and `/path/to/php/bin/php` do not exist. Have you read the page I linked in my comment? Did you run `whereis php` to find out the path?

Comment: @kerbholz i checked the path and its below and i replace the path as well did not worked either
`php: /usr/bin/php`    `/usr/bin/php7.2`

i added like this

Comment: Now that we know where PHP is, you can use `* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/artisan shows:fetchrss >> /dev/null 2>&1` to run your artisan command from a cronjob. (Although you should rather run Laravel's scheduler every minute and schedule your artisan command inside Laravel)

Comment: added  `* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/artisan shows:fetchrss >> /dev/null 2>&1
`
 nothing happen and its running as well

`Jan 21 10:05:01 liedergut CRON[6018]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/artisan shows:fetchrss >> /dev/null 2>&1)
`

Comment: How do you know "nothing happens", how do you check that? No idea what your artisan command is supposed to do (maybe there is no RSS to fetch?)

Comment: worked with this 
`* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/artisan shows:fetchrss >> /dev/null 2>&1`

i was checking into database if data is inserted or not .. 
now check and its work 


@kerbholz thanks alot it was php path wrong

Comment: No problem, I made it an answer with some suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most certainly `/var/www/html/php` and `/path/to/php/bin/php` do not exist. You can find out where the `php` executable is by using `whereis php` (as you stated in your comment, it is `/usr/bin/php`). So to make your artisan command run every minute your cron line should be

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/artisan shows:fetchrss >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

I would suggest though to run Laravel's scheduler every minute:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

and schedule your artisan command inside of Laravel, as written [on Laravel's task scheduling documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/scheduling). This way you can manage your scheduled jobs or re-schedule them without having to edit/touch your crontab.

Answer (score 0):

This command works for me

```
* * * * * cd /var/www/html/projectname && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```